# Can't make ClientScriptManager do anything

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Following situation: The following code is added to a control, which is dynamically loaded by a page. The page itself uses a masterpage:

```
Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    Dim myScript As String = "alert('hello')"
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "MyScript", myScript, True)
End Sub
```

So far, no alert happens. If I search for the js-code in the HTML-source-code, I can't find anything. What do I need to do to make the manager to output the registered stuff?

Thx for any tipps
sl3dg3

Answer (score 0):

How is you control being loaded and added to the page?  The following works fine, with your code in the init event of the HelloControl.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim control As HelloControl = CType(LoadControl("HelloControl.ascx"), HelloControl)
    Page.Controls.Add(control)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hmmm, it is basically done like this, or at least in a very similar manner... (the environment is a complex one, though). I guess I need to rebuild a trivial example.